# Could someone explain what the use for this piece of code is?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, enumerate, python-turtle

I started this pixel art project using turtle in Python, and I used some code online to help me out, and it works, but I am not sure why it works and what it does. Could someone help me out here? Thanks!

This is the code I would like to know more about:

```
x0 = -widthCover / 2 * sizePixel
y0 = heightCover / 2 * sizePixel

for i, row in enumerate(gameCoverPixel):
    setposition(x0, y0 - i * sizePixel)
```

This is my full code for reference:

```
from turtle import *

sizePixel = 30
sizeCursor = 20
bgcolor('navy')

coverColors = {
    'B': 'saddle brown',
    'T': 'tan1',
    'W': 'snow',
    'P': 'darkorchid1',
    'R': 'orangered',
    'Y': 'gold',
    'F': 'firebrick4',
    'G': 'gray34',
    'Q': 'black',
    'X': 'salmon4',
}

gameCoverPixel = [
    'WWWWWBBBBBWWTTTTBWWWWBBBBBBBWWWWBTTTTWWBBBBBWWWWW',
    'WWWBBBBBBBBTTBBBBBBWBBBBBBBBBWBBBBBBTTBBBBBBBBWWW',
    'WWBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBWBTTTBBBTTTBWBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBWW',
    'WBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBWBTWWWTBTWWWTBWBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBW',
    'WBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBTBTWWWWTWWWWTBTBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBW',
    'WBBBBBBBBTBBBBBBTTBTWWWQTQWWWTBTTBBBBBBTBBBBBBBBW',
    'WBTTTTBBTBBBBBBBTTBBTWWTTTWWTBBTTBBBBBBBTBBTTTTBW',
    'TTTTTTTTWBBBBBBBTTWWWTTBBBTTWWWTTBBBBBBBWTTTTTTTT',
    'TTTTTTTTTWBBBBBTTWWWWWTTTTTWWWWWTTBBBBBWTTTTTTTTT',
    'TTTTTTTTTWWBBBBTTBWWWBWWWBWWWBWWTTBBBBWWTTTTTTTTT',
    'TTTTTTWTTWWBBBBTTBBWBBBWBBBWBBBWTTBBBBWWTTWTTTTTT',
    'WTTWTTWWWWWWBBBBTTWWWBWWWBWWWBWTTBBBBWWWWWWTTWTTW',
    'WWTTWTTWWWWWBBBTBTTTWWWTTTWWWTTTBTBBBWWWWWTTWTTWW',
    'WWWWWWWWWWWBBBBTTBBTTTTTTTTTTTBBTTBBBBWWWWWWWWWWW',
    'WWWWWWWWWTTBBBBTTTTBBBBBBBBBBBTTTTBBBBTTWWWWWWWWW',
    'WWWWWWWWTBBBBBBTTTBTTTTTTTTTTTBTTTBBBBBBTWWWWWWWW',
    'WWWWWWWWWBBBBBBBTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTBBBBBBBWWWWWWWWW',
    'WWWWWWWWWBBBBBBBBTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTBBBBBBBBGGGGWWWWW',
    'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWGXXXXXGWWWW',
    'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWGXXXXXXXGWWW',
    'WWWRRRWWWRRRWWRWWWRWRWWRWRRRWRWWWRWWWGXXXXXXXGWWW',
    'WWWRWWRWRFYFRWRRWWRWRWRWWRWWWWRWRWWWWGXXXXXXXGWWW',
    'WWWRWWRWRYYYRWRWRWRWRRWWWRRWWWWRWWWWWGXXXXXXXGWWW',
    'WWWRWWRWRFYFRWRWWRRWRWRWWRWWWWWRWWWWWGXXXXXXXGWWW',
    'WWWRRRWWWRRRWWRWWWRWRWWRWRRRWWWRWWWWWWGXXXXXGWWWW',
    'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWGGGGGWWWWW',
    'PPPPPPPPRPPRPPRRRPPRPPPRPPRRRPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
    'WPWWWPWWRPRWWRFYFRWRRPWRWRWWWPWWWPWWWPWWWPWWWPWWW',
    'PWPWPWPWRRPWPRYYYRPRPRPRPRPRRWPWPWPWPWPWPWPWPWPWP',
    'WWWPWWWPRWRPWRFYFRWRWWRRWRWPRWWPWWWPWWWPWWWPWWWPW',
    'PPPPPPPPRPPRPPRRRPPRPPPRPPRRRPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP',
]

widthCover, heightCover = len(gameCoverPixel[0]), len(gameCoverPixel)

screen = Screen()
setup((widthCover + 3) * sizePixel, (heightCover + 3) * sizePixel)

tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
hideturtle()
shape('square')
shapesize(sizePixel / sizeCursor)
penup()

x0 = -widthCover / 2 * sizePixel
y0 = heightCover / 2 * sizePixel

for i, row in enumerate(gameCoverPixel):
    setposition(x0, y0 - i * sizePixel)

    for pixel in row:
        color(coverColors[pixel])
        stamp()
        forward(sizePixel)

tracer(True)
exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code calculates the starting point of the image, in this case it's centering (i.e. `/ 2`) the image on the window:

```
x0 = -widthCover / 2 * sizePixel
y0 = heightCover / 2 * sizePixel
```

Given turtle's coordinate system, with the origin in the middle of the window, we expect the starting X coordinate to be negative and the starting Y coordinate, for a top down image, to be positive.

This code is looping over all the strings of the image, setting the starting point of each row.  To get the index of each string in the image array, we use `enumerate()` to generate a number for each string, starting at 0:

```
for i, row in enumerate(gameCoverPixel):
    setposition(x0, y0 - i * sizePixel)
```

Each row starts at the same X coordinate, the `x0` calculated in the previous code snippet.  The Y coordinate is the `y0` calculated earlier plus some progression down the window determined by the string's index and the height of the pixels that are being drawn.  This is a subtraction as the Y coordinate decreases as we move down the window away from the title bar.